# How to download entire content of web page with wget (First Page)

Tags: linux, shell, web, download, wget

I would like to download entire contents of web page. (Only First page)

I need only first page. No Recursive

How can I do this with wget for windows.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/14403.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself.

This is the shell that I created

```
@echo off
echo Hello this is Deniz's webpage downloader
set /P theuserinput="Please Enter website that you like to download: "

wget.exe -p %theuserinput%

pause
```